# Image not updating in DataList

Tags: image, visual-studio-2010, datalist

I'm showing company logos in a `datalist` along with a few fields.
All works fine until I overwrite logo with a new one (same filename),
`datalist` still shows the old `image`, even if I manually go to the `filesystem` and delete what its looking at!
After I `upload` the new `image` (before I manually deleted)I looked in the folder and it is the correct one there

I'm referencing the `filesystem` folder and file like so:

```
ImageUrl='<%# "~/icons/" + Eval("ImagePath") %>' Height="200px"
```

Am I missing something obvious?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rebind your new `DataSource` to your `DataList` object after updating your images? Apparently, you may have forgotten to update and rebind your `DataSource` I guess.

```
if(!Page.isPostBack)
{

     // ...
     // Getting updated data set logic...
     // ...

dataListObject.DataSource = yourDataSource; // setting updated datasource
dataListObject.DataBind();                  // binding updated datasource
}
```